# Rospack command not found in makefile when trying to build

Tags: ros, build, rospack, makefile, buiding-errors

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
I'm a beginner with ROS and I'm having trouble to build my first packages.

If a use 'rosmake rxtools', for example, I get a 'rospack failed to build' message.

I haven't found how to solve this so I tried to manually make this package, by going to its root directory and running 'make'. When I do this, I get the following message:

```
sudo make
make: rospack: Command not found
Makefile:1: /cmake.mk: No such file or directory
make: *** No rule to make target `/cmake.mk'.  Stop.
```

The Makefile looks like

```
include $(shell rospack find mk)/cmake.mk
```

So, it seems to me that the rospack command can not be found inside the makefile. I did some little test modifications in the makefile trying to verify this:

```
test=$(shell rospack find mk)
#include $(shell rospack find mk)/cmake.mk
all:
    @echo Command result: $(test)
```

Which gives me this result:

```
make: rospack: Command not found
Command result:
```

But I have no idea of why the rospack command cannot be found, neither how to solve this.

I'll really appreciate any sugessitons about how to continue to debug this.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/30554/rospack-command-not-found-in-makefile-when-trying-to-build/) by [manu](https://answers.ros.org/users/2009/manu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 61 on 2012-03-27

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Solved this, it was a permission problem when trying to build.

---

Originally posted by [manu](https://answers.ros.org/users/2009/manu/) with karma: 61 on 2012-04-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1